# PyQGIS standalone gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll error

Tags: pyqgis, standalone

This is my code in a batch file

```
REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%

REM Python Setup
REM set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin\gdalplugins;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python StandAlone_Field.py
```

My error messages are:

```
gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll error
unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much but error messages are still same. Somehow path setting in my system is not correct.